# How to convert screenshot object into file object in Ashot selenium

Tags: selenium, cucumber

I wrote a java method whose return type is file. This method grabs a screenshot of screen with Ashot and store it on a Screenshot object. I need to convert that screenshot object into file object so that I can return file object.

```
   public static File grabScreenshot() {

    try {       

 Thread.sleep(Integer.parseInt(Property.getProperty("screenshotDelay")));

    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }       

    File screenshot=null; //creating null file object to return

    Screenshot screenshot1 = new AShot().shootingStrategy(new ViewportPastingStrategy(1000)).takeScreenshot(driver());

    //Here I have to typecast the screenshot1 to file type so that I can return
    return screenshot;
}
```

Comment: can you show us your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick

```
// getImage() will give buffered image which can be used to write to file
BufferedImage bi = new AShot()
            .shootingStrategy(ShootingStrategies.viewportPasting(100))
            .takeScreenshot(driver).getImage();

File outputfile = new File("image.jpg");
try {
    ImageIO.write(bi, "jpg", outputfile);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

// Print the absolute path to see where the file is created
System.out.println(outputfile.getAbsolutePath());
```

Comment: @dgsanket .. Kindly accept the answer if it helped.